# Is there any free and up-to-date e-book for Linux programming (C/C++/GNU)?

Tags: c++, c, linux

Is there any free and up-to-date e-book for Linux programming (C/C++/GNU)?

If there is not any free e-book, what is the best (most up to date) book for Linux programming?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408838/good-book-for-c-programming-on-linux

Comment: Specically, what aspect of Linux programming are you interested in? Network server programs? GUI programs? Kernel modules?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux Programming Book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851980/linux-programming-book)

Comment: @Rob: I want to start linux programming from hello wolrd.

Comment: This specifically asks about free e-books whereas the other questions mentioned discuss books that are paper books and not free.  Nevertheless, the overlap is very considerable and you could have saved people some time by pointing out the related questions you looked at explaining why they're not satisfactory.

Comment: I learned Unix programming by reading the `man` pages (it was in 1986, Stevens did not write yet his book).

Answer (score 3):

The **GNU C Programming Tutorial** by Mark Burgess, licensed under GNU Free Documentation License

Comment: [The GNU C Programming Tutorial](http://www.crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/)